# django mysql dependency reference error

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hi I have django website and am trying to battle with migrations in django 1.7. Having just updated and it working locally I want to get it woking on my staging server however I get this error: --> KeyError: u"Migration users.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'auth', u'0002_auto_20151030_1801')"

Locally this doesn't complain. I upgraded django locally, removed South and used makemigrations and migrate and everything worked ok. However if i push an already migrated version to my remote server, this error appears. I need to be able to deploy and have the same version locally, on staging and on production servers.

More information -> i can't find where my auth app migration files are stored. when i grep 0002_auto_20151030_1801, this is the name of another migration in mailings app, which is strange? or maybe that is normal.

Any advice would be hepful. I've only been working with django for a year and just upgraded to 1.7 with built in migrations.

Here's the traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 245, in build_graph
    self.graph.add_dependency(migration, key, parent)
  File "/webapps/commoncause-staging/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 46, in add_dependency
    "Migration %s dependencies reference nonexistent parent node %r" % (migration, parent)
KeyError: u"Migration users.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'auth', u'0002_auto_20151030_1801')"
(env)fcc@staging:/webapps/commoncause-staging/commoncause/ekologi$ grep -r 0002_auto_20151030_1801 *
Binary file mailing/migrations/0002_auto_20151030_1801.pyc matches
Binary file users/migrations/0001_initial.pyc matches
users/migrations/0001_initial.py:        ('auth', '0002_auto_20151030_1801'),
```

Comment: Migrations changed starting from Django 1.7. You should read [Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/) documentation. The command `syncdb` was deprecated in favor of the new `migrate` command

Comment: Thanks César, i'm not using syncdb and have read through the documentation countless times. I used migrate on my local branch, then pulled it remotely and when i use migrate remotely i get this error. any ideas why?

Comment: Good to know, it was just a suggestion since I read you are upgrading to 1.7. About the error, editing the question and pasting the full traceback can help.

Comment: cool thanks for the suggestion, i read back my comment and realised it sounded a little abrupt. sorry been on this problem all day ;-) i will update my question :-)